# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘desk’: package ‘desk’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it

Tags: r, package

i am curently writing my thesis and i need to install a package called desk. It is not possible to download it from Repository(Cran), i downloaded it from this website: http://vwl3.ovgu.de/Lehre/desk.html
So far no problem, i changed install from: Repository(Cran) to Package Archive and changed install to library:"C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.3/library.

So when i try to install and open it i get this result. I am also running RStudio as an Administrator but nothing works and changed the library. I also updated R but nothing works.

> R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10) -- "Bunny-Wunnies Freak Out"
> Copyright (C) 2020 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

> install.packages("C:/Users/ridva/Downloads/desk_1.0.2.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary", lib="C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.3/library")
> package ‘desk’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

> library(desk)
> Fehler: package or namespace load failed for ‘desk’:
> package ‘desk’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it

Comment: I think you will have to contact the maintainer of that package.

Comment: It looks the Windows binary version they provide was not built with the latest version of R. You can try installing the source version assuming you've setup RTools and such to be able to compile your own packages on your machine: `install.packages("http://www.vwl3.ovgu.de/vwl3_media/Downloads/desk/desk_1.0.2.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")`

Comment: @MrFlick, thanks a lot. Finally it works!